# debian7 cron.allow & cron.deny files

Tags: debian, security, cron, configuration, hardening

Almost 3 weeks that, in my downtime, I try to find out where the files `cron.allow` & `cron.deny` are located in **debian7** distro. No way, it seems that by default they are not in the system.

'Just' for hardening purposes, I would have those files available in my system. My question is actually if I can just `touch` them and use them without have to make other configurations.

```
root@asw-deb:~# touch /etc/cron.allow
root@asw-deb:~# touch /etc/cron.deny
```

Or if I may have to 'map' those files, maybee editing some cron configuration files, 'saying' where cron can find the two files I created.

Sorry if I sound a little nooby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manual `man 1 crontab`:

```
If the /etc/cron.allow file exists, then you must be listed (one user per line)
therein in order to be  allowed to use this  command. If the /etc/cron.allow file
does not exist but the /etc/cron.deny file does exist, then you must not be listed
in the /etc/cron.deny file in order to use this command.

If neither of these files exists, then depending on site-dependent configuration
parameters, only the super user will be allowed to use this command, or all users
will be able to use this command.

If  both  files  exist  then  /etc/cron.allow  takes  precedence.  Which  means that
/etc/cron.deny is not considered and your user must be listed in /etc/cron.allow in
order to be able to use the crontab.

Regardless of the existance of any of these files, the root administrative user is
always allowed to setup a crontab. For standard Debian systems, all users may use
this command.
```

I gave it try on Debian 7, and it is working exactly this way.

Comment: Wops! I have not thought to look in the man!! so silly! thankyou! Great also i don't have to do nothing, because only the root was exaclty what i wanted!

Comment: I'm not sure that you can add root to cron.deny